# Excel VBA , run time error -2147417848

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am running a UserForm that allow users scan with a barcode and print on a Worksheet , i also have a label that show's the count for the total scanned pieces so far. When i get to 170-180 scanned pieces it gives me an Run Time Error.

```
Run Time Error

'-2147417848 (80010108)

Method 'Cells' of object_WorkSheet' failed



If KeyCode = 13 Then
    'Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(1, 30) = Now()
    last = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    Length = Len(registos.TextBox3.Text)
    If Length > 32 Or Length < 1 Then
        MsgBox "O código inserido não tem um nº de caracteres válido!", vbExclamation
        'registos.Hide
        'registos.Show
        registos.TextBox3.Text = ""
        registos.TextBox3.SetFocus
            Else
                If registos.TextBox3 <> "" And registos.TextBox1 <> "" And registos.TextBox2 <> "" And registos.TextBox4 = "" And registos.ComboBox5 <> "" Then
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Visible = True
                    WS_Count = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
                    For j = 1 To WS_Count
                        Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(j).Unprotect Password:="stockregistos"
                    Next j
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(last + 1, 1) = Now()                                               'data
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(last + 1, 6) = registos.Label11.Caption                            'cc
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(last + 1, 5) = registos.Label20.Caption                               'ano fiscal
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(last + 1, 7) = a1logiin.TextBox1.Text                              'OPERARIO
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(last + 1, 8) = registos.TextBox1.Text                              'referencia formata
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(last + 1, 9) = registos.TextBox2.Text                              'ordem
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(last + 1, 10) = registos.TextBox3.Text                             'codigo
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(last + 1, 11) = 1                                                  'quantidade
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(last + 1, 12) = registos.ComboBox1                                 'Entrada/Saida
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(last + 1, 13) = registos.ComboBox5                                 ' ESTADO
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(last + 1, 14) = Format(registos.ComboBox3, "#")                    'CODIGO DEFEITO
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(last + 1, 16) = registos.ComboBox6                                 'ORIGEM DEFEITO
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(last + 1, 17) = registos.TextBox5                                  'OBSERVAÇÕES
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(last + 1, 18) = registos.ComboBox7                                    'TIPO
                    contador = contador + 1
                    registos.Label21.Caption = contador
                    GoTo fim2
                End If
fim2:
                If registos.ComboBox1 = "SAÍDA" And registos.TextBox3 <> "" And registos.TextBox1 <> "" And registos.TextBox2 <> "" And registos.TextBox4 = "" And registos.ComboBox5 <> "" And registos.ComboBox2 <> "" Then
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(last + 2, 1) = Now()                                                 'data
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(last + 2, 6) = registos.ComboBox2                                    'cc
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(last + 2, 5) = registos.Label20.Caption                               'ano fiscal
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(last + 2, 7) = a1logiin.TextBox1.Text                                'operario
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(last + 2, 8) = registos.TextBox1                                     'referencia formata
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(last + 2, 9) = registos.TextBox2                                     'ordem
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(last + 2, 10) = registos.TextBox3.Text                               'codigo
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(last + 2, 11) = 1                                                    'quantidade
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(last + 2, 12) = "ENTRADA"                                            'Defenir saída de um CC como a entrade de outro
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(last + 2, 13) = registos.ComboBox5                                   ' ESTADO
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(last + 2, 14) = Format(registos.ComboBox3, "#")                      'CODIGO DEFEITO
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(last + 2, 16) = registos.ComboBox6                                   'ORIGEM DEFEITO
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(last + 2, 17) = registos.TextBox5                                    'OBSERVAÇÕES
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos").Cells(last + 2, 18) = registos.ComboBox7                                    'TIPO
                    GoTo salto
                End If
            registos.Hide
            registos.Show
            registos.TextBox3.Text = ""
            registos.TextBox3.SetFocus
    End If
    registos.Hide
    registos.Show
    registos.TextBox3.Text = ""
    registos.TextBox3.SetFocus
 End If
```

I added some more code , so you can understand what's going on and maybe see something that i didn't realize.

Comment: See how to build a [MCVE].

Comment: Looks like the method "cells" of "object_worksheet" failed. Would need to see some code though to know why.

Comment: I edited my question with some code , hope it helps.

Comment: Drop the `Application.` qualifier in front of `ThisWorkbook`. Give the `Registos` sheet a code name (set its `(Name)` property in the properties toolwindow / F4) to e.g. `RegSheet` and then get rid of all these redundant `Worksheets("Registos")` calls, you can then simply do `RegSheet.Cells(...).Value = ...` instead

Comment: Do you mean this `ThisWorkbook.Application` ?@MathieuGuindon

Comment: `Application` has nothing to do here. `ThisWorkbook` is already an unambiguous named object that can only ever refer to the workbook that contains the VBA code that you're looking at.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates some overload. You could try to restucture the code in a way to put every (most of the) repeated instructions into a sub/function as the sub/function releases all variables (incl. objects) on return and so frees up memory.

I have some more suggestions/questions:

1. I would use `With ... End With` like this:

   ```
   Dim regSh as Worksheet
   Set regSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Registos")
   With regSh
       .Cells(last + 2, 1) = Now()
       .Cells(last + 2, 6) = registos.ComboBox2
       ....
   End With
   ```

This method will load the sheet object into the memory only once and keeps it there until `End With` resulting in some performance improvement.

2. I would restructure the code to avoid `GoTos`.
3. It is a bit obscure why you `Me.Show` the sheet immediately after `Me.Hide`
4. It looks like you unprotect all sheets in the workbook in every loop. Are you sure this is necessary? It needs quite an effort.

Comment: I did clean and restructure my code , deleting almost every `GoTo` and fixing `Me.Show` and `Me.Hide` as well the protection loop , but still having the same run time error.

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is in `last`

Comment: Good news! Getting closer to the bug. It is rather unusual to count over the last row but it looks safer to insert a control before referencing the cell like `If last + 2 > ActiveSheet.Rows.Count Then Stop`

Comment: Not quite sure if i understand what you mean , why `If last + 2...` and no `If last + 1 ...`

Comment: You get `last` as the last used row but what happens if you reference a cell 2 rows after the very last possible row? So check before you write.